# Push new View Controller from destination View Controller (swift)

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboardsegue

I'm trying to get a destination View Controller to push a new View Controller, but I can't seem to get it, programmatically or via storyboard segues.

Here's what I'm trying to do:

I have 3 View Controllers (let's call them A, B, and C). All three were created (designed?) in the storyboard. I start on view controller A, and when the user presses a button, I want to present view controller B modally, and then when the user selects a cell in view controller B, I want view controller B to be dismissed (modally), and I want view controller A to push a a new view controller (view controller C).

The way I've tried to implement this thus far is when the user presses the button in view controller A, I programmatically modally push view controller B, and then when the user selects a cell in view controller B, I segue back to view controller A, and try to push view controller C from view controller B's prepareForSegue function like this:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if let viewA = segue.destinationViewController as? ViewControllerA {
        let cell = sender as! ViewControllerBTableViewCell

        var viewC = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("viewControllerC") as! ViewControllerC
        viewC.IDToDisplay = cell.userID
        viewA.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewC, animated: true)
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

However, when I run this... view controller C is never pushed!

The reason I need to push view controller C from view controller A is that I need the user to be able to navigate back to view controller A from view controller C using the "back" button... not back to view controller B from view controller C.

Essentially the flow I am trying create is view A -> view B modally -> view C ---> back to view A as if view B disappeared (because it should). **Please note**, however, that view B does need to be able to set the `IDToDisplay` value of view C before view A pushes to view C.

Is there a clean (standard) way to implement this? Or am I going to have to get janky?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this problem in two ways

first option: you can create one clousure var in your B controller and execute it before you dissmiss the B controller

for example: In BController

```
class BTableViewController: UITableViewController {
     var pushClosure:(()->())?


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

      pushClosure?()
      self.navigationController?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)      
    }

}
```

And in A controller in the prepareForSegue do something like that

```
   override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "SegueID" {

        let nextView:BController = segue.destinationViewController as! BController
         nextView.pushClosure = {
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("SegueID To C Controller", sender:nil)   
        }
     }
   }
```

The second Option is to implement your own delegate
in the BController

```
protocol ClassNameDelegate{

 func pushToC()

}

class ClassName: NSObject {

  var delegate:ClassNameDelegate?



    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

      self.delegate.pushToC()
      self.navigationController?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)      
    }
 }
```

And in A controller

```
 class AViewController:ClassNameDelegate{ 

  func pushToC(){
     self.performSegueWithIdentifier("SegueID To C Controller", sender:nil) 
  }

  override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
       if segue.identifier == "SegueID" {
           let bController:BController = segue.destinationController as! BController
           bController.setDelegate = self
        }
   }
}
```

I hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks the reply! The delegate option seems like the standard approach... the only problem is that when I implemented it, when I call the delegate function from controller B, view controller B gets dismissed, but nothing happens. When I write a print statement in the delegate function in controller A, it doesn't ever get printed. Is there any reason that the delegate function wouldn't fire when called in view controller B?

Comment: Figured it out, the function wasn't firing in view controller A because view controller A was never set as the delegate for view controller B (oops, didn't know I had to do this). Setting view controller A as the delegate for view controller B when I instantiate view controller B and present it fixed the issue.

Comment: I'm glad it solve your problem, if it solve the issue, can you check the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Is the user pressing a button in viewController C?
If so, you can use this:

```
self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
```

just add it to where you press the button in viewController C and it should go back to A

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't really address my question: it doesn't matter what the user does in viewController C, I want them to be able to get back to view A naturally by pressing the "back" button on the navigation bar.